# Unexpected token import with Webpack and Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I added react-router v4 to my project with Webpack and NodeJS. The app compiled correctly without any error messages in the log, but the browser console gave me this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3391)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1405), <anonymous>:11:25)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1405), <anonymous>:24:27)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1405), <anonymous>:25:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1405)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:3379), <anonymous>:12:17)
```

I think that the problem is in the Webpack configuration. This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin')
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new NpmInstallPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['eslint'],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        ],
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        ],
        test: /\.js$/,
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      },
      {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
  }
}
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "redux-ru-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Redux RU tutorial",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Yuriy Shipovalov",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.4.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.16.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.12",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-redux-router": "0.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-logger": "2.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './containers/App'
import './styles/app.css'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

const store = configureStore()
console.log(store.getState())
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
          <Route> path="/" component={App}></Route>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to set Babel's plugins and presets directly in the Webpack configuration as part of `module.loaders`. This is incorrect. You have to pass it as options to the *loader*. The error is because you're passing the options incorrectly so Babel does not receive the options, and thus does not transpile your code based on the presets and thus the error.

Depending on your Webpack version, try:

**Webpack 1.x**

Since you have multiple loaders, you *cannot* set it in the [`query`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters) object. Instead, you are going to have to set your loader options *inline*:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react?plugins[]=transform-runtime']
}
```

This will directly pass the loader options to Babel through a query, but since you have two loaders Webpack didn't know which loader to query so you have to do it inline on one loader.

Comment: Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list

Comment: @ЮрийШиповалов Oh, you've got *two* loaders. Get rid of the query and try `loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,react?plugins[]=transform-runtime']`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem :(  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import. The error remained the same

Comment: I dont't think so. The error appeared after adding react router v4 in my project. I thought that it was because of missing preset es2015 in webpack.

Comment: @ЮрийШиповалов Actually, I had the wrong inline loader syntax. I've edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example from [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/):

> `module.rules` allows you to specify several loaders within your webpack configuration. This is a concise way to display loaders, and helps to maintain clean code. It also offers you a full overview of each respective loader.

In your case, you can:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: [
          'react-hot','babel-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is? If you're talking about my answer I can give you a reference, https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders, Does webpack 1.12.12 use `rules` instead of `loaders`? Anyhow, it's backwards-compatible.

Comment: No, Webpack 2.x is backward compatible. 1.x is not.

Comment: Yes, `webpack 2` is backwards-compatible. Please keep in mind I'm talking about `webpack 2` here.

Comment: Yeah, but the question uses 1.12.12.

Comment: The example above is `webpack 2` as well. Please read the docs

Comment: I get *that*, but the question is using Webpack 1.12.12.

Comment: I see. I thought you were referr1ing to my answer.