# Unexpected token using inline dynamic import with webpack for code splitting

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I followed the tutorial on how to do code-splitting with Webpack.

But, when building, it doesn't recognize inline `import`s.

Normal `import`s e.g. `import join from 'lodash.join` work, however.

This SO Question: [Unexpected token import with Webpack and Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427482/unexpected-token-import-with-webpack-and-babel) asked for the same thing but is still unanswered. So, I created a repository that you can replicate to observe the behavior in a more straightforward manner.

Git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/jpls93/code-demo && cd code-demo && git checkout unexpected-token-import &&npm install &&npm install && npm run build
```

Gif demo:
[image]

Error message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the plugin [`babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) to your babel config.

I've forked your repo and committed the fix. See [commit](https://github.com/andykenward/code-demo/commit/aa6d99a36af6865f3ee4bd7aa78c88c84b13ac6e).

But you will run into another error as you are using async and await.
[image]

As you babel config in your `webpack.config.js` is using [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) the default is to compile for the last 2 versions of browsers (which includes IE 10).

So you need to configure your babel config for the browsers you want to support and add the [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/). I've [committed](https://github.com/andykenward/code-demo/commit/4b3f01c0f588e5b78013d00cc2071a168e8517f1) a quick fix that uses [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) and the default browsers presets in [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env). I've turned on [`debug`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#debug) so you can see what babel plugins are being used.

[image]

You could also just use [`babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) to support async. But I find using [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) config much nicer so you can use native browser code when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
// package.json
 "devDependencies": {
+ "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",

// webpack.config.js
 options: {
   presets: ["env"],
+  plugins: ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
 }
```

Thanks @andykenward. Saw your [fork](https://github.com/andykenward/code-demo/commit/aa6d99a36af6865f3ee4bd7aa78c88c84b13ac6e).

Comment: Thanks. I was too slow answering.